# sed and variables-substitutions on an custom script

Tags: bash, sed, variable-substitution

well i ask here because i have around 12 hours trying with examples on internet for put a replace with sed on a custom script.

In the file a had a lots of lines but i want to replace values after "=" are the follow

```
[Paths]
config=
data=
mupen64plus=
plugins=
roms=

[Plugins]
audio=
input=
rsp=
video=
```

Values i need to put in results after replace : Well i need the result of variable "$PWD" not literally "$PWD"

```
[Paths]
config="$PWD/Datos/config"
data="$PWD/Datos/config"
mupen64plus="$PWD/$EJECUTABLE"
plugins=./.libs/64Bits/plugin
roms="$PWD/Roms"

[Plugins]
audio=mupen64plus-audio-sdl
input=mupen64plus-input-sdl
rsp=mupen64plus-rsp-cxd4-sse2
video=mupen64plus-video-glide64mk2
```

Because for too much hours i try things like this :

```
sed -i "s|mupen64plus=.*\"|mupen64plus="$PWD/"$EJECUTABLE\"|g" "file.conf"
```

This not make something on file

another varations like :

```
sed "s#^(mupen64plus=).*#\l ${"\/`pwd`"//#/\\#}#" "file.conf"
```

Show "bad substitution" or something like that

Another things i try and don't work :

```
sed 's:#mupen64plus=:'`pwd`':' "file.conf"
```

This :

```
sed -E "s/(data=).*/\1\.\/Datos\/\config/" "./file.conf"
```

Make this replacement :

```
data=./Datos/nfig

sed -E "s/(data=).*/\1\.\/Datos\/\c\/o\/nfig/" "./Datos/config/mupen64plus-qt.conf"
data=./Datos/oo/nfig

sed -E "s/(data=).*/\1\.\/Datos\\co\nfig/" "./Datos/config/mupen64plus-qt.conf"
data=./Datos/
```

well or is much easer use another thing like awk, someone can help me with this, please ?

Answer (score 2):

With your skeletton config file

```
VAR1=/home/archemar
VAR2=some/lib
sed -e "/^mupen64plus/s:=.*$:=${VAR1}/${VAR2}:" \
    -e "/^config/s:=.*:=${VAR1}/DataOs/config:" config
```

where

- first two lines initialize variables
- `-e` in sed introduce edit command
- `/^mupen64plus/` apply to lines beggining with (`^`) pattern (here fixed string `mupen64plus` )
- `s: : :` substitue, use `:` as separator instead of `/` so slashes don't need to be escaped
- `=.*` replace `=`, any char (`.`), any number (`*`) till end of line (a `$` is superfluous as `*` will match as many as possible)
- `=${VAR1}/${VAR2}` by `=` and value of `${VAR1}/${VAR2}` (**actual expansion is done by calling shell (likely bash)**, that's why we need double quotes instead of single quotes)

result is

```
[Paths]
config=/home/archemar/DataOs/config
data=
mupen64plus=/home/archemar/some/lib
plugins=
roms=

[Plugins]
audio=
input=
rsp=
video=
```

I would advise against inplace edition (`-i`), or use a backup file

```
sed -i .bak "/^mupen64plus/s:=.*$:=${VAR1}/${VAR2}:
    /^config/s:=.*:=${VAR1}/DataOs/config:" config
```

another  way is a here document

```
cat <<END-OF-FILE > config
[Paths]
config="$PWD/Datos/config"
data="$PWD/Datos/config"
mupen64plus="$PWD/$EJECUTABLE"
plugins=./.libs/64Bits/plugin
roms="$PWD/Roms"

[Plugins]
audio=mupen64plus-audio-sdl
input=mupen64plus-input-sdl
rsp=mupen64plus-rsp-cxd4-sse2
video=mupen64plus-video-glide64mk2
END-OF-FILE
```

which will write a config file with all variable expanded

Answer (score 1):

After many hours searching I found this (whilst looking for AWK usage examples), [Using sed to replace Windows path with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43764493/4424636).

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764493/using-sed-to-replace-windows-path-with-numbers#comment74570863_43764742) I saw the following:

```
sed -i 's^<customTag>C:\\path\\to\\'${OLD_VER}'</customTag>^<customTag>C:\\path\\to\\'${NEW_VER}'</customTag>^g' test.txt
```

I solved with these commands:

```
sed -i "s/[.].*//" "./Datos/config/mupen64plus-qt.conf"
sed -i "s/[:/].*//" "./Datos/config/mupen64plus-qt.conf"

sed -i 's^mupen64plus='${VIEJO}'^mupen64plus='${PWD}'/'${EJECUTABLE}'^g' ./Datos/config/mupen64plus-qt.conf #Especifica el binario ejecutable que se utilizara
sed -i 's^config='${VIEJO}'^config='${PWD}'/'Datos/config'^g' ./Datos/config/mupen64plus-qt.conf
sed -i 's^data='${VIEJO}'^data='${PWD}'/'Datos/config'^g' ./Datos/config/mupen64plus-qt.conf
sed -i 's^plugins='${VIEJO}'^plugins='${PWD}'/'.libs/64Bits/plugin'^g' ./Datos/config/mupen64plus-qt.conf
sed -i 's^roms='${VIEJO}'^roms='${PWD}'/'roms'^g' ./Datos/config/mupen64plus-qt.conf
```